# problem with numpy library multiply an inverted squared matrix with the original matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I came across a problem when using the numpy library in a matrix-class that i created myself. I am using the numpy.matmul() and numpy.linalg.inv() to multiply and invert matrixes and as far as I have understood you're supposed to return a unit/identity matrix when multiplying a matrix with its inverted result. So I have these functions:

```
def matmul(matrixOne, matrixTwo):
    return np.matmul(matrixOne, matrixTwo)

def invert(squaredMatrix): 
    return np.linalg.inv(squaredMatrix)
```

They work as they are supposed to when used separately but when I test to see if it returns a unit matrix I do this:

```
original = [[1,2], [3,4]]

print("here is result",str(matmul(original,invert(original))))
```

and I should get a matrix like this one: `[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]` in the print, but instead I get: `[[1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00] [8.8817842e-16 1.0000000e+00]]`
Are there any data types I am supposed to convert to make this work or what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by floating point error. The value 8.8817842e-16 is very, very close to 0, but sometimes while operating on floats, the value you get isn't exactly right.

Another example: 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004